# How to call another function after complete bserverside ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

How to call another function after complete bserverside ajax function ,

```
..................
"fnServerData" : function( sSource, aoData,fnCallback) {

      $.ajax({
                 "dataType" : 'json',
                 "type" : "GET",
                 "url" : sSource,
                 "data" : aoData,
                 "success" : fnCallback
            });
};
```

I tried

```
    .........
    "fnServerData" : function( sSource, aoData,fnCallback) {

      $.ajax({
                 "dataType" : 'json',
                 "type" : "GET",
                 "url" : sSource,
                 "data" : aoData,
                 "success" : fnCallback
            });
      alertFunction();
};

      function alertFunction(){
      alert('hi');
      }
```

but it will call before the completion.

Comment: You need to call that function inside "fnCallback" function after ajax success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can chain it with `.always()`:

```
$.ajax({
     "dataType" : 'json',
     "type" : "GET",
     "url" : sSource,
     "data" : aoData,
     "success" : fnCallback
}).always(function(){ // add it here.
  alertFunction();
});
```

or you can add `"complete"`:

```
$.ajax({
     "dataType" : 'json',
     "type" : "GET",
     "url" : sSource,
     "data" : aoData,
     "success" : fnCallback,
     "complete": alertFunction
});
```

Answer (score 1):

User callback functions like below

```
    "fnServerData" : function( sSource, aoData,fnCallback) {

      $.ajax({
                 "dataType" : 'json',
                 "type" : "GET",
                 "url" : sSource,
                 "data" : aoData,
                 "success" : fnCallback
            })
            .done(function(resp){
               alertFunction();
             })
            .fail(function(resp){
               alert("server error");
             });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code,

```
     $.ajax({
                 "dataType" : 'json',
                 "type" : "GET",
                 "url" : sSource,
                 "data" : aoData,
                 success : function(data)
                 {
                     alertFunction();   

                 }

  });
```